# isAfter isBefore Java 8 LocalDateTime One Day Different

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, backend

I want to compare two dates with today date. Does isAfter and isBefore best for this? isAfter and isBefore cant detect one day changes. Lets say:

```
If today is 20 Nov. I put in range 20 Nov-21 Nov.

if(todayDate.isAfter(startDate) && todayDate.isBefore(endDate))
{
  // task
}
```

This code wont detect that today is in range. OR / || is not applicable because I have a set of range to be tested. Any idea on this?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be able to detect that?

Comment: Why don't you add an `||` testing for `isToday()`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis both checks are `strict`

Comment: @jiaweizhang cant understand you sir.

Comment: isAfter and isBefore are not isAfterOrEqual and isBeforeOrEqual

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will solve it: Just add a check for whether today's date it either the start or end date which you will have to implement yourself

```
if( (todayDate.isAfter(startDate) && todayDate.isBefore(endDate) ) || (todayDate.isEqual(startDate) || todayDate.isEqual(endDate) )
{
     // task
}
```

This is because `isAfter` and `isBefore` are both strict.

**Edit:** A better more logical solution:

```
if(!todayDate.isAfter(endDate) && !todayDate.isBefore(startDate))
{
    // task
}
```

By negating `isAfter`, it becomes endDate or before.

By negating `isBefore`, it becomes startDate or after.

Comment: Thank You ! The first code runs very well. The second code seems like not working ^^'

Comment: Sorry, you have to switch the startdate and enddate in the second one